# Dynamically adding menuStrip items

Tags: c++-cli

so I have a problem with dynamically adding items to menuStrip. I mean I know how to add items to it, but I dont have any idea how to make Click handler to those dynamically added items.

```
for(int i = 0; i < grupiuKiekis; i++)
    {
        row2 = mysql_fetch_row(result2);
        System::String^ grupesName = gcnew String(row2[1]);
        pasirinktiGrupęToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->Add(grupesName);
    }
```

Please show me the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Add method has several overloads. You could use the [overload that allows you to specify an EventHandler explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160942.aspx), or you could construct a [ToolStripItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.aspx), set up a [click handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.click.aspx) on that, and then [add the ToolStripItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxdt0s8t.aspx).

### Edit

Here's basically what you want to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < grupiuKiekis; i++)
{
    row2 = mysql_fetch_row(result2);
    System::String^ grupesName = gcnew String(row2[1]);
    ToolStripItem^ item = gcnew ToolStripItem();
    item->Text = grupesName;
    item->Click += gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form1::clickHander);
    pasirinktiGrupęToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->Add(item);
}

void clickHander(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    ToolStripItem^ item = (ToolStripItem^) sender;
    System::String^ grupesName = item->Text;
    // Do what you need to do.
}
```

Comment: Well, I know how to make a clickHandler for button, but how to make a clickHandler on dropDownItems?

Comment: DropDownItems is a list, not the thing the user is clicking on. You're adding a click handler on the ToolStripItem.

Comment: I still do not understand... Ok, so can you explain how should I make it?

Comment: Becouse the thing what i want to do, is:
get few things from MYSQL database and add it to menustrip dropdownlist. Then, when i select item from dropdownlist, i want to read that items name.

Comment: ToolStripItem^ item = new gcnew ToolStripItem();
you need to change to
ToolStripMenuItem^ item = gcnew ToolStripMenuItem;

Thank you for your answer :]